# I can't get this form from html work in php with the post method

Tags: php, post

I'm just learning as everyone, I've tried to search for an answer on internet, I did the exact same thing as other people did and I can't get to work it

Here is my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Login Database </title>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
    <h1> Test 2019</br>Prova</h1>
    <h2> Login </h2>
    <form methond="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="username"> </br>
    <h2> Password </h2>
    <input type="password" name="password"> </br>
    </br><input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <input type="submit" value="Accedi">
    </center>
    </form>
</body>
```

And there is my test.php

```
<?php
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
echo "My username is $username </br> and my password is $password";
?>
```

Comment: Typo in `methond="POST"`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in:

```
<form methond="POST" action="test.php">
```

methond => "**method**"

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change methond="POST" on method="POST". And

```
<?php

$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];

echo "My username is " . $username . "  </br> and my password is " . $password;
```

Comment: Yes, you can continue the line. echo "My username is " . $username . "  </br> and my password is " . $password . " Add some text" ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your form tag you have written methond instead of method.
For future questions you should probably tell what happens on submit rather than "not working".

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "My username is " . $username . "  </br> and my password is " . $password;
```

hello i'm the guy that commented your question

you need to write $username and the variables you want to display the content of, OUTSIDE the quotes okay ?
so do it like this

1) I open the quotes
2) I write the text I want to display
3) then I close the quotes
4) and I write the name of the variable I want to display the content off, and I link this to my text, with a POINT between the quote, and the $username !
5) and I close the quotes and I put the ";" (or I can continue my phrase by adding a point, then opening the quotes, writing etc etc...)